# How to compare two Arraylists values in JSP

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jstl

I have two arraylists that I have passed to my JSP.  I can loop through and display their values separately, as in

```
<c:forEach var="Headr" items="${requestScope.listHeadrs}">
    <c:out value="${Headr.headrid}"/> :
    <c:out value="${Headr.headr}"/> :
    <c:out value="${Headr.headrdescr}"/><br>
</c:forEach>  

<c:forEach var="Funct" items="${requestScope.listFuncts}">
    <c:out value="${Funct.functid}"/>, 
    <c:out value="${Funct.funct}"/>, 
    <c:out value="${Funct.functheadr}"/>, 
    <c:out value="${Funct.functdescr}"/><br>
</c:forEach>
```

However, I am trying to loop through both, to find the instances where the value from one (${Headr.headr}) matches a value from the other, (${Funct.functheadr}).

I tried the following, but get errors on the 'if' statement:

```
<c:forEach var="Headr" items="${requestScope.listHeadrs}">
    <c:forEach var="Funct" items="${requestScope.listFuncts}">
        <c:if test="${Funct.functheadr}" == "${Headr.headr}">
            <c:out value="${Funct.funct}"/>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Any ideas how this might be accomplished?

The compile errors (Eclipse) are as follows:
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Missing required attribute "test"
- Undefined attribute name
"Headr.headr"
- Undefined attribute name "eq"
- Undefined attribute name "$
{Funct.functheadr}"
- Invalid location of text (}) in tag
(<c:if>).
- Invalid location of text (${) in tag
(<c:if>).
- Invalid location of text (") in tag
(<c:if>).
- Invalid location of text (== ") in tag
(<c:if>).